# Two columns to appear side by side when viewed on the tablet device - bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="row col-lg-12" id="productBrief">
    <div id="RaspberryAndChocolate" style="display:none; height:200px;">

        <div class="col-lg-6"> @*-- Floats Left*@
            <img src="~/Content/Images/YogurtImages_404x290/image1.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 5%" alt="Image alt" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6" id="productDesc"> @*-- Floats Right*@
            <h2 class="raspberryRed productLineHeight">FLAVOUR #3</h2>
            <h1 class="raspberryRed">
                RASPBERRY &<br /> WHITE CHOCOLATE
            </h1>
            <p class="productPara">
                A decadent combination of whole raspberries and smooth white chocolate that you will want to make last as long as possible. Teaspoon recommended.
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class="label label-as-badge" style="font-size: 0.9em; padding:3%"><a href='@Url.Action("Products", "Products")' class="colourWhite">VIEW ALL FLAVOURS</a></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when viewed on a desktop they are aligned side by side which looks great, when viewed on a Ipad productDesc appears under productBrief it looks like two rows, how can I change this so they appear side by side when viewing on an ipad? I'm new to bootstrap so I'm trying to get my head around cols etc

Comment: try using `col-xs-6`

Comment: @JosanIracheta As you commented first and was the answer, would you make your comment an answer then I can give you the points? Also as they works for the ipad is there a way I can say if mobile show one per row so productDesc appears under productBrief?

Comment: This class is suited for mobile phones. So for mobile phones, the columns will stack. I will write an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class <del>`col-xs`</del> `col-sm` will adjust so that the columns are stacked when viewing the page on a mobile device. Unlike `col-md` and `col-lg`, the columns will stay side-by-side until the window is at mobile phone width, which I believe is around 360px.

**EDIT**

In the Bootstrap documentation, it states that the breaking point is at 768px. Therefore the columns will be stacked when the window width is less than 768px while using <del>`col-xs`</del>.

[I created a demo that shows when the columns stack](http://jsfiddle.net/7md25zbj/)

Comment: Not quite right. `col-xs-*` never stacks (except in some arguably buggy extreme edge cases).

Answer (score 0):

Add col-sm-6 on both div, should fix it !

Check [grid section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) on bootstrap site.

Answer (score -1):

Thats called web responsive, please read [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for clear explanation about grid.

Ofcourse it wont viewed side by side when you look at small device like tablet or iPad since there some rules

`.col-xs-` for extra small devices (<768px)

`.col-sm-` for small devices (>=768px)

`.col-md-` for medium desktop (>=992px)

`.col-lg-` for large desktop (>=1200px)

So, lets say you had `<div class="col-lg-6">` means it half of container which had 12 grids (unless you modify at LESS), div will viewed side by side when you open it at large devices since it use `col-lg-` , if you want to view it side-by-side on tablet which small devices, consider use `col-sm-6`